# Запятая после слова "Видимо"

Tags: пунктуация

"Видимо(,) нас недопоняли Боги."
Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 5):

Запятая нужна, т.к. слово "видимо" является вводным, а вводные слова обособляются.

Answer (score 2):

"Видимо(,) нас недопоняли боги." Здесь "видимо" является вводным словом, так как
  1) обозначает отношение говорящего к тому, что он сообщает, и выражает большую (или меньшую) степень уверенности;
  2) не является членом предложения, ни к данному слову, ни от него не поставить вопрос к другим членам предложения.
Пример, когда ВИДИМО не является вводным словом. Она ВИДИМО изменилась за лето: поправилась и похорошела. (То есть изменения её внешности можно увидеть).

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от значения. Если "видимо" здесь можно заменить на "возможно", то запятая нужна, так как вводное слово. Если тут стилизация под несовременную речь и "видимо" означает "явно", то запятая не ставится. Ср. *Папенька видимо был в духе.* А. Фет, "Первый заяц". *Тимофей Семеныч видимо подобрел.* Ф. Достоевский, "Крокодил".

P.S. "Боги" (во мн. ч.) хоть по Лопатину, хоть по Розенталю пишутся только со строчной буквы.

Comment: В приведенных Вами примерах возможны оба варианта, так как и наречие, и вводное слово  вписываются в структуру простого предложения. А вот в начале предложения при заданном порядке слов ВИДИМО может быть только вводным словом.